# users enter results only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this script in my results controller:

```
 distribution_sheet = DistributionSheet.find(:all, :conditions => ["lifecycle_state = ?","open"]).last


   if distribution_sheet.nil?
     redirect_to root_path  #you could redirect somewhere else if you want
      flash[:notice] = "There are currently no active EQAs"
  # elsif (@result.size > 1)
  #   redirect_to root_path  #you could redirect somewhere else if you want
   #   flash[:notice] = "You have already entered your EQA for EQA number #{distribution_sheet.id}"
    else
    flash[:notice] =      "EQA number #{distribution_sheet.id} is open for submissions"
  end
```

result is a model.  I need the users to input new results when the DistributionSheet is 'open' ONLY ONCE.  The elsif above doesnt seem to work.  Any advice?

Here is where the @result was referenced:

```
    def new
   @result = Result.new
   distribution_sheet = DistributionSheet.find(:all, :conditions => ["lifecycle_state = ?","open"]).last
   @result.distribution_sheet_id = distribution_sheet.id
  10.times do
            @result.specimen_results.build

  end
  specimen_ids  = distribution_sheet.specimens.collect{|specimen| specimen.id}
  @result.specimen_results.each do |specimen_result|
        specimen_result.specimen_id = specimen_ids.shift
  end

   @result.lab_id = current_user.lab_id

  end
```

Comment: You need to include the code that references @result.

Comment: Let me know if you manage to read your own code pasted as comment. What about editing your question and presenting it properly?

Comment: dont worry about the 'specimen_results' etc.  The @result.lab_id = current_user.lab_id says that each user who has his own lab_id can view their own results only.  I need to allow this user to enter results only once.

Comment: Not formatting your code is a sure way to discourage people from helping you.

Comment: Yes, sorry, late at night and falling asleep!

Comment: @Jamie Wong: Passive aggressive messages are not what Stack Overflow is about. We need to be welcoming to the new people. They don't know they're doing things wrong.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg: it wasn't intended as passive aggressive, but I can see how it comes accross that way. I have to disagree that most people don't know they're doing things wrong - any programmer knows that if they're presenting code to another dev, readability matters. Mike, if you're legitimately new to programming and are unsure of how to format your code, then I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. By doing this:

```
 distribution_sheet = DistributionSheet.find(:all, :conditions => ["lifecycle_state = ?","open"]).last
```

You're loading the every single `DistributionSheet` object in your database that meets those conditions. It may seem quick now, but when you've got a ton of records it will take a while. Best to do this instead:

```
distribution_sheet = DistributionSheet.first(:conditions => "lifecycle_state = 'open'", :order => "id DESC")
```

That'll accomplish the same goal but won't load the entire association first of all, just the one record you need.

Secondly, perhaps rather than checking `@result.size > 1` you should be checking it on the association instead:

```
distribution_sheet.results.count > 1
```

This will do an SQL query to count the number of `results` for a `distribution_sheet` object. You need to have a `has_many :results` in the `DistributionSheet` model first.

So a couple more things: I would recommend reading the [Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) as well as the [Association Basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to learn the basics you need in order to solve this problem correctly.